# User annotation overlay in HTML5/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an application that auto-generates a report page.
I.e. a HTML5 webpage with plots and tables.

In some cases users need to edit mark certain details in the report, so they take screenshots/copy paste content into Microsoft Word or similar and then edit it.

I would like to enable the user to do annotation on top of the report inside the browser. For instance draw a circle on top of a spike in a plot. Or insert an arrow pointing at something important. and adding a comment next to it.

They can then print/save the report to pdf including their annotations.

This should not be too hard to do using canvas for drawing and so on. But I guess there should be some framework/library doing that. I just can't find it.

Do you think this makes sense to do and do you know any libraries that supports that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean something like [Annotator](http://annotatorjs.org/).

Comment: Yes! I don;t knwo how I was not able to find that. 

I see there is also a plugin for doing annotation on images.

Thank you!